# FluentValidation/MVC/ASP Identity: How to get the current user Id when validating model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, asp.net-identity, fluentvalidation

1) I'm trying to allow the user to change their UserName (email) etc. in a ASP.MVC/Identity app. Using FluentValidation I'd like to check that no other user is using the new email.

In a controller I'd use User.Identity.GetUserId() but this isn't available when building Validation rules. How can I retreive the currently authenticated userId?

```
public class ManageUserViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ManageUserViewModel>
{
    public ManageUserViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(e => e.UserName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Måste ange din e-post adress.")
            .EmailAddress()
            .WithMessage("Ogiltig e-post adress.")
            .Must((model, _) => UserMethods.IsUserNameAvailable(model.UserName, "userId???"))
            .WithMessage("E-post adressen är upptagen.");
    }

    ...

}

[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(ManageUserViewModelValidator))]
public class ManageUserViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "E-post*")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

2) What is the best way to store such changes. Right now I'm using AutoMapper:

```
public static void Update(this DbContext context, ManageUserViewModel model, string userId)
    {
        User user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id.Equals(userId));
        Mapper.CreateMap<ManageUserViewModel, TessinUser>();
        Mapper.Map(model, user);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

3) In my header I display the currently logged in user using `User.Identity.GetUserName()` but after I've changed the UserName this text isn't updated. I need to logout and login again to update this. Is there a way to get ASP to update the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I'm trying to allow the user to change their UserName (email) etc. in a ASP.MVC/Identity app

Asp.net identity has a class called [UserManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468199%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). This class exposes many function including [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457229%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) which will automatically update the user's data in UserStore.

> Using FluentValidation I'd like to check that no other user is using the new email.

If you use [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457221%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) function of UserManager class for creating new user then this function automatically take care about the duplicate username entry validation. In case of invalid Or duplicate entry, [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457221%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) function return well descriptive error messages which you can show to your users.

> 2) What is the best way to store such changes. Right now I'm using AutoMapper:

I don't understand the code you mentioned in your 2 point. The only purpose of [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) is to mapped one object to another. In that code

- you fetch the user from the database
- create a mapping configuration *(You should do this thing only once, no need to create mapping configuration again and again. So the best place for such type of things is global.asax file)*
- Then you mapped your viewmodel object to domain model object.

But this thing never put any change in the current context, so *context.SaveChanges()* have no effect.

And i think this is the reason why your User.Identity.GetUserName() is not updated.

Comment: Thanks I'll try Update() will probably solve all my problems. Thanks for clarifying where to put mapping configuration.

Comment: I've got all steps working using UpdateAsync but I User.Identity.GetUserName() isn't updated? Can this be forced somehow?

Comment: do you updating user using ajax ?

Comment: No using backen controller.

Comment: ok, but i mean to say by which way you are sending the request to controller, an ajax request OR a form post ? Because if it is an ajax than username text will not update, you have to update the text username manually